# RewriteRule Last flag being ignored

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, flags

I don't get that if a rewrite rule matches and it has the Last [L] flag that it still executes the rules beneath. I redirect all calls to the public folder but I've added an exception for images, but the exception is being ignored. I thought that with the [L] flag if a rule matches it stops looking for rules beneath.

This is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^image/(.*)/?$ image.php?t=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^$ public/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1 [L]
```

If I remove the bottom 2 rules it does work.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

It is not ignored.
It is the specific of .htaccess.
It reruns every time URL is changed.

Try this instead.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} rewritten
RewriteRule .* - [L]

RewriteRule ^image/(.*)/?$ image.php?t=$1&rewritten=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule ^$ public/?rewritten=1 [L,QSA]
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1?rewritten=1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you it works and I understand why, but it isn't there a simpler way to do it?

Comment: There is. Put your original rules to httpd.conf in the VirtualHost section.